# How prove this inequality $\frac{a^2+bc}{3+a}+\frac{b^2+ca}{3+b}+\frac{c^2+ab}{3+c}\le \frac{7}{4}$

Tags: inequality

let $a,b,c\ge 0$,show that
$$\dfrac{a^2+bc}{2a+b+c}+\dfrac{b^2+ca}{2b+c+a}+\dfrac{c^2+ab}{2c+a+b}\le\dfrac{7}{12}(a+b+c)$$

My idea: Without loss of generality,we Assmue that
$$a+b+c=3$$
then we only prove this 
$$\dfrac{a^2+bc}{3+a}+\dfrac{b^2+ca}{3+b}+\dfrac{c^2+ab}{3+c}\le \dfrac{7}{4}$$
then I can't,Thank you very much

Comment: Why is this assumption without loss of generality? I believe it (I have also seen it elsewhere too), I just do not understand it... Can you please explain it shortly

Comment: @Stefanos putting $a=\lambda a$ ,$b=\lambda b$,$c=\lambda c$ $\lambda $ cancels out

Comment: @user129901 Ok, wait, if $a=7$, $b=11$ and $c=19$ what is $λ$? (sorry, I am simply stucked..)

Comment: @Stefanos you can use $\lambda $ to make a+b+c to any value you wish i.e. if you prove it for (a+b+c) then it also holds for $\lambda (a+b+c)$

Comment: @user129901 Ok, thanks a lot mate, I got it. I owe you one!

Comment: @Stefanos. I agree with you that the title and the text may be confusing; however, what does the OP is correct.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, of course, it is just that I am not so familiar with that kind of exercises and I found the chance to ask. No doubt about his corectness.

Answer (score 0):

After full expanding we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^4+3a^3b+3a^3c-10a^2b^2+66a^2bc)\geq0$$ or
$$2\sum_{cyc}(a^4-a^3b-a^3c+a^2bc)+5\sum_{cyc}ab(a-b)^2+64abc(a+b+c)\geq0,$$
which is true by Schur.

Done!